# How to identify host machine Mac address from vm machine Mac adrress

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

How to identify host machine Mac address from vm machine Mac adrress

Example: in our Network we scan and found  one of the  vm machine  Kali Linux is install. And also get Mac address and ip address of that machine. Mac adrress belong to vmware inc. we want to identify physical machine where this vm machine was installed

Thanks for reply Clifford,

but i am asking about Vm workstation (not Esxi and Vcenter). some one installed Kali linux on Vm worksation.

Answer (score 0):

You left out some key information, like if you are using vCenter or just ESXi? Do you have access to vCenter.

The easiest way is to just login to your ESXi host or vCenter and right click the VM and edit and check the each nic properties until you find the MAC.

If you environment is large and you have vCenter, you can use PowerCli. You will need access to vCenter.

Download PowerCli here: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/VMware.PowerCLI/11.5.0.14912921

```
Install-Module -Name VMware.PowerCLI    

Import-Module VMware.VimAutomation.Core

Connect-VIServer -Server <IP/FQDN> -Protocol https -User <username> -Password <password>

Get-VM | Get-NetworkAdapter | Where {$_.MacAddress -eq “XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX”} | Select-Object Parent,Name,MacAddress

Get-VMHost -VM <name of VM you got from Get-VM>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Clifford,

but i am asking about Vmware workstation (not Esxi and Vcenter). some one installed Kali linux on Vm worksation.